# Deleted IMAP account/Personal folder.... safe to delete *pst files?

Tags: imap, pst

I recently deleted IMAP accounts in Outlook 2007 as well as a Personal Folder that was no longer essential. (Just in case I repented of that decision, the Personal Folder was backed up and transferred over to a laptop running Outlook.)

During some PC housekeeping I noticed that the amount of free space on my hard disk had dropped by about 6Gb.

It occurred to me (possibly pretty obvious to everyone else here!) that deleting the IMAP accounts and the folder in Outlook itself didn't delete the data files from my system. The size of these files accounts for the loss of the disk space.

I need to regain the space. Could someone kindly tell me: is it safe simply to delete the .pst files?

Comment: If you backed up the files to another storage location then feel free to delete the files.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly safe to delete PST files.  Just be sure to remove them from Outlook, if they are mounted.  Here is how: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291636/en-us